# angular 8+ how get timespan value from string in format "PT2M20.000989S"

Tags: angular, date, timespan

i write angular-cli app and from api got timespan value "PT2M20.000989S"
How i can convert it to date object or time object?

I try `new Date("PT2M20.000989S")`, but is not working with message 'Invalid Date'

Comment: timestamp should be number only.

Comment: i don't use timestamp, i use timespan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the ISO-8601 duration format. The P stands for period and is (optionally) followed by a duration in years (Y), months (M), weeks (W) and days (D). The T stands for time, and is followed by one or more of hours (H), minutes (M) and (fractional) seconds (S).

You can use moment package for parse this format

Install Moment via in terminal

> npm install moment --save

then import moment in your component

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

and use this sample:

```
var moment = require('moment');
var duration = 'PT2M20.000989S';
var x = moment.duration(duration, moment.ISO_8601);
console.log(x);
```